# How to avoid ansible playbook abort, when any one host fails among many?

Tags: error-handling, ansible

My scenario is, I have large set of hosts as inventory to the ansible playbook with strategy free and ignore_errors options enabled. If any of the host fails (say undefined variable error) with their task, the entire playbook gets aborted, and due to that all remaining hosts also gets impacted even if they are successful with their tasks.

I came to know about max_fail_percentage option and i tried that by reproducing a similar scenario but with no luck. For example, my expected outcome is, among 10 servers as inventory, if 2 servers fails, playbook should continue to execute the tasks for the remaining 8 servers.

##########################

I am just posting porting of my playbook where issue encountered for better understanding.

- name: Check if file exist
  stat:
  path: /tmp/file.tmp
  register: file_status
- name: Set fact status variable if file do not exist
  set_fact:
  fstatus: "FALSE"
  when: not file_status.stat.exists
- name: Set fact status variable if file do not exist
  set_fact:
  fstatus: "TRUE"
  when: file_status.stat.exists
- name: Execute script if file exist
  shell: python script.py
  register: result
  when: fstatus == 'TRUE'

In this case, stat module failed due to python interpreter mismatch and hence fstatus variable was not set unfortunately. This lead to below error and failure of the playbook,

ERROR! The conditional check 'fstatus == 'TRUE'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional fstatus == 'TRUE': 'fstatus' is undefined

##############################

Comment: "_ansible playbook with ..._", can you share your inventory and your playbook so that one might be able to understand and reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should ensure that the all variables exists with

```
when: var1 is defined and var2 is defined
```

for your tasks which use these variables. If the variables do not exist, then the corresponding task will be skipped and all other task will be executed.

Edit after question change:

you should reduce the 4 tasks to this:

```
name: Check if file exist 
  stat: 
    path: /tmp/file.tmp 
  register: file_status
name: Execute script if file exist 
  shell: python script.py 
  register: result 
  when: file_status is defined and file_status.stat.exists
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your response, I have added my actual issue in the question section for better understanding. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Thankyou Oliver, this works. I was not aware of 'defined' and this really would help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the default ansible behavior.
If a host fails it is removed from the batch and ansible continue the rest of the tasks on the remaining hosts.

Your problem is related to an undefined variable, and this "always" breaks the palybook. `fstatus` is not defined for all hosts. Add what Oliver suggested to avoid that error.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Oliver's suggestion fixed my issue.